# Automorphic Forms on $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I have been reading Armand Borel's book,  *Automorphic Forms on $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$*. In his second chapter entitled "Review of $SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, Differential Operators and Convolution", Borel presents a standard bases for Lie(G) = { $M \in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}) \: | \: \text{trace}\: M = 0 $ }. Namley $$
   H =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right],   E =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 \\
   0 & 0\\
  \end{array} } \right] ,   F =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$$
He continues to say that if we consider the upper half complex plane $\mathbb{H}$ and if we denote $V^*$, the Vector Field on $\mathbb{H}$ defined by $V \in $ Lie(G), and since $G = SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ operates on the left on $\mathbb{H} = \frac{ SL_{2}(\mathbb{R})}{SO_2}$ , then the map $V \mapsto V^*$ extends to an anti-isomorphism of $\: \mathcal{U}(\mathbb{g})$ (the universal enveloping Algebra) onto an algebra of differential operators on $ \mathbb{H}$.

He then states that we may wirte $e^{tV}(z) = x(t) + i y(t)  \: \: \:  (z \in \mathbb{H})$, and the value of $V^*_z$ of $V^*$ is $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \bigg{|}_{t =0} \: \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{dy(t)}{dt} \bigg{|}_{t =0} \: \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$
From all this Borel claims that it is easy to check that $$E^* =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\\ F^* = (y^2 - x^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - 2xy \frac{\partial}{\partial y},\\
 H^* = 2x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + 2y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$ My question is, how would i even begin to verify what $E*, F^* $ and $H^*$ are? Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\exp(H t) = \pmatrix{\exp(t) &0\\ 0 &\exp(-t)}, \exp(H t).z=\frac{\exp(t) z+0}{0z+\exp(-t) }=\exp(2t) z$, $\frac{d}{dt}(\exp(H t)z)|_{t=0} = 2 z$, $E^2 = 0, \exp(t E) = I+tE, \exp(tE). z = z+t,\frac{d}{dt}(\exp(E t)z)|_{t=0} = 1$, $F^2=0, \exp(Ft) =I+tF, \exp(Ft). z = \frac{z}{t z+1}, \frac{d}{dt}(\exp(F t)z)|_{t=0} = -z^2$. Then the differential operator is $M_z^* = \Re(\frac{d}{dt}(\exp(M t)z)|_{t=0} 2 \frac{\partial}{\partial z})$. How will those things be affected by the operations of $M_2(\Bbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{g})$ ?

Comment: Thank you for your time. It is not immediately obvious to me as to why its worth mentioning that both $E$ and $F$ are nilpotent

Comment: $\exp$ is defined by a power series with infinitely many terms

Comment: yes thank you i see that now